# Sort vector of queue

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, queue

Someone knew how can I sort queue of queues, which items I've bet in vector of queues?

```
queue<int> sortedQueue(queue<queue<int>> mainQueue,int countOfChild)
{ 
    queue<int> sorted;
    vector<queue<int>> childQueues;
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfChild; i++)
    {
        queue<int> x = mainQueue.front();
        mainQueue.pop();

        childQueues.push_back(x);
    }
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Give an example of data in Queues and how you want to sort them.

Comment: Sorting is usually done using the less-than operator `<` for comparison. Now, for two queues, what would make one less than the other? When you know that, you can implement that as an overloaded `operator<` function and just call [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with the vector.

Comment: data in queue are integer number and i want to sort in ascending order                example:                                                                                                                     firstQueue:5 6 9 10                                                                                                                                   secondQueue:1 2 3                                                                                                                                end result is: 1 2 3 5 6 9 10

Comment: @Some programmer dude `<` operator is defined for `std::queue` as lexicographical comparison of sequences made of queues' elements. Nonetheless, I agree that before sorting a sequence of queues one should think about the meaning of one queue being less than another queue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a vector of queues is as easy as typing `std::sort(a_vector_of_queues.begin(), a_vector_of_queues.end())` where `a_vector_of_queues` is `std::vector<std::queue<T>>` and `T` is any type which has `<` operator defined for it like `int` or `std::string`.